# Trying to get IM details of a contact - the imType is always 3

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to get the IM details of a contact and store this in a POJO:

```
            String imWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
            String[] imWhereParams = new String[]{objContactsHelper.id, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
            Cursor imCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, imWhere, imWhereParams, null);

            while (imCur.moveToNext()) {
                String imName = imCur.getString(imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA));
                int imType = imCur.getInt(imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.TYPE));

                System.out.println(imName);
                System.out.println(imType);

                String imTypeLabel = ctx.getResources().getString(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.getTypeLabelResource(imType));
                objContactsHelper.putIM(String.valueOf(imType), imName);
            }

            imCur.close();
```

here is the sample system.out:

```
08-03 16:45:49.829    1984-2001/com.epcrm.exa.exacrm I/System.out﹕ Megatron
08-03 16:45:49.829    1984-2001/com.epcrm.exa.exacrm I/System.out﹕ 3
08-03 16:45:49.829    1984-2001/com.epcrm.exa.exacrm I/System.out﹕ Megatron@Cybertron
08-03 16:45:49.829    1984-2001/com.epcrm.exa.exacrm I/System.out﹕ 3
```

I have saved two IM details for a contact but every time the imType is coming as 3 - which results in overriding the previous values.

How to overcome this? I am sure that I have two different types for IM in the address book.

Here is a screen grab of what the contact details look like:

[image]

My test Environment is:
IDE: Android Studio
OS - Desktop: Ubuntu
OS - Android: Android 5.1 API 22 (Emulator / Physical Device)

Comment: Try using protocol instead of type.

Comment: I did that, no desired result

Answer (score 3):

Please try this,

```
String id = cur.getString(cur
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            Cursor imCur = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                            + " = ? AND "+ ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL +" in (5,6,7,1,8,4,3,2,0)", new String[] { id }, null);
            while (imCur.moveToNext()) {
                String imName = imCur
                        .getString(imCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA));
                int imType = imCur
                        .getInt(imCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL));

                System.out.println("im: name: "+imName);
                System.out.println("im: type: "+imType);
            }
            imCur.close();
```

Where `5,6,7,1,8,4,3,2,0` are `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL`.

**Update:**

```
public static final int PROTOCOL_MSN
```

Added in API level 5
Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)

and

```
public static final int PROTOCOL_SKYPE
```

Added in API level 5
Constant Value: 3 (0x00000003)

So its correct values that you get in your case.

Refer [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.html) for more information.

Comment: This does not help, as I mentioned I had tried this already. Here is the result I get: 

`"messenger": {
                "1": "Megatron@Cybertron",
                "3": "Megatron"
            },`
1 and 3 translating to work and home whereas I would like something like Skype and AIM

Comment: Just to mention that PROTOCOL_CUSTOM has the value (-1).